# Tests for mediation between Binary DV and binary IV by a continuous mediator

Tags: generalized-linear-model, t-test, binary-data

This is my first time working with binary outcomes in R and I'd be grateful for some advice.

I've got an experiment where subjects are in 1 of 2 conditions (A or B) and either succeed or fail in a test (1/0 as the main DV). After the treatment is administered and the main DV is measured, the subjects are measured on one continuous third continuous variable (M) that can range from 1-7. I also measure controls like sex, age, and experience (both 1-7 scale and also a binary). I'd like to test:

1) whether the DV significantly varies as a function of the IV - Or are the population averages 50% vs. 70% significantly different as a function of which treatment they receive)- My understanding is that binary logistic regression would be all that is required for this, or is there anything else?

2) Whether the effects of the above still hold when controlling for age, sex, and experience - I think again a binary logistic regression would be appropriate and adequate for this?

3) Whether the mediator (M) differs by treatment - Would a simple T test be appropriate for this?

4) Whether the mediator actually mediates the relationship between the IV and the DV.
 I've seen reference to the sobel test, bootstrapping, etc. Are there industry standards for doing this binomial DVs, binomial IVs (since I've only got 2 conditions) and continuous mediators?

Is the coding for the mediation testing easy to do in R?

Thank you!!